# utop no longer supporting camlp4?

Tags: ocaml, camlp4, utop

I wanted to use a package which has some camlp4 extensions in utop, but I get:

```
utop # #camlp4o;;  
utop was built without camlp4 support.
```

This is with utop version 2.0.1 and OCaml 4.05.0.

I installed utop with opam. Is there a way to rebuild utop with camlp4 support?

Comment: I see this comment in the CHANGES.md file for utop: "* Drop support for camlp4/camlp5" - that was for version 2.0.0. This seems unfortunate, since a lot of documentation like Real World OCaml depend on camlp4 support in utop.

Comment: On the bright side, Real World OCaml is currently being updated to match these changes. :)